# Sublime text useful questions

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I think most of us sublime text users have one or more of these questions. Let's get it answered here:

1) What is the default font of Sublimetext and where can I download it from?

It says:

```
"color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/LAZY.tmTheme",
"font_size": 11
```

But what font it is? It looks good.

2) How can I make the brackets bold and red/other color when I point there?

Currently, I can see there is small line underneath the brackets but it is not bold nor it is any color

```
{
    code
}
```

3) Can I run Python/Java code from sublime text?

4) How can I print a file using sublime text?

5) Is there any easy way to comapre files using sublime text?

6) Can I run MySQL queries from sublime text?

Thanks!

Comment: please only ask one question at a time. several of your questions already have answers on SO or other places, please use google.

Comment: If you search SO I think you'll find that all of these questions have already been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Emilbus Mono

2) There is a nice little plugin available that allows you to customize the matching tag highlighting style and behavior: https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter

3) Tools > Buils System... > Python

4) There is no direct way to print from ST, but you can use something like the sublime text to html plugin

5) https://github.com/colinta/SublimeFileDiffs or an external tool like Kaleidoscope for Mac.

6) Try SublimeMysql on github

Comment: Download the file itself from github (the "Download ZIP" button), then copy the folder in the zip into Sublime Text's "Packages" folder. You can get the location of this folder by looking at SublimeFileDiffs' github page's "Installation" section. It will vary depending on your OS.

Answer (score 0):

4) No you can't print from Sublime Text.

Comment: but there are plugins for that - just check Package Control

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use 'Tools' -> 'Build System' -> 'Python' or 'Java'
2. It has not such feature. But you can use plugin https://github.com/joelpt/sublimetext-print-to-html and print from a browser.
3. Plugin https://github.com/colinta/SublimeFileDiffs
4. 'Tools' -> 'Build System' -> 'New Build System'

   {
    "cmd": ["mysql", "-u", "USERNAME", "-e", "source $file"],
    "selector": "source.sql"
   }